# How to create ring shape drawable in android?

Tags: android, shapes

with this code I get just a border:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="15dp"
    android:thickness="2dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="#4d4d4d" />

</shape>
```

how can I make a ring shape like below image :

[image]

Comment: But why you need to do this in Android, if you can just make this shape in photoshop and use it as drawable?

Comment: I think using a shape in android is better than a shape in photoshop.

Comment: I wonder if using VectorDrawable is also a good choice, instead of the other solutions.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

2dp outer ring with a 2dp gap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#4d4d4d" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#4d4d4d"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: How to use the ring?

Answer (score 44):

You will need to create a drawable and set it as a background.

`shape_primary_ring.xml`

```xml
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="4dp"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</shape>
```

**Preview**

[image: Ring Drawable Preview]

Answer (score 5):

Ring drawable is juxtaposition of elements, use layer-list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:right="6dip" android:left="6dip">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:innerRadius="0dp"
           android:shape="ring"
           android:thicknessRatio="3"
           android:useLevel="false" >
      <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
      <stroke
          android:width="5dp"
          android:color="@color/maroon" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:right="20dip"
        android:left="20dip"
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:top="34dip">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle"
           android:innerRadius="0dp">
      <solid android:color="@color/maroon" />
      <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:right="20dip"
        android:left="20dip"
        android:bottom="34dip"
        android:top="0dip">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle"
           android:innerRadius="0dp">
      <solid android:color="@color/maroon" />
      <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Xml drawable by all means more useful than static images, they can be correctly scaled without need of .9 library or generating set of different sizes from Gimp, Photoshop

Answer (score 2):

> I think using a shape in android is better than a shape in photoshop.

Correct, creating a drawable it's better because you can change the colour or shape with code instead of creating a new image resource, for example.
Create a `FrameLayout` with 2 `Views` and a `TextView`. The first view background would be your outer ring (shape) and the second a filed circle (shape). Finally the last `View` (bigger z-index) your `TextView`:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <View/><!-- (outer ring)-->
   <View/><!-- (filed circle)-->
   <TextView/><!-- (text)-->
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="120"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="140">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape
            android:angle="0"
            android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: like This]

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<item>
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="4"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="15"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <solid android:color="@color/white_color" />
        <size
            android:height="48dip"
            android:width="48dip" />
    </shape>

</item>
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:thickness="55dp"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="@color/white_color"/>
        <size android:height="200dp"
            android:width="200dp"/>
        <stroke android:color="@color/green_color" android:width="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: How does one stop the stoke making a line on the right hand sid of the ring?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:innerRadius="10dp" android:shape="ring" android:thickness="2dp" android:useLevel="false">
                <solid android:color="#dfdfdf" />
            </shape>
        </item>
     </selector>
```