# Draw Circle in Preview in CameraX describing TapToFocus

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am trying to implement TapToFocus feature using the CameraX Api .I have implemented it successfully but not able to know how to draw a circle on the preview describing the Location pressed by the user .

[I want to have a circle in the preview like the image has](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trMVV.jpg)

Comment: This [response](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/160269606#comment10) from the CameraX issue tracker might help you.

Comment: I am not able to find how to sign in above at the site . There is no create account method there . Please Guide .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The are many ways to draw and animate a focus ring around a tap position on `PreviewView`, some fancier than others. One simple way of doing so is to:

1. Create a `Drawable` of the ring, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55912971/4718283) for instance.
2. Layout an `ImageView` containing the `Drawable` on top of `PreviewView`, and initially hide it.

```
<FrameLayout ...>

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        ... />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/focusRing"
        android:src="@drawable/focus_ring"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        ... />

</FrameLayout>
```

3. Set up a touch listener on `PreviewView`. On a touch event, use the event's coordinates to show the ring around it.

```
private void animateFocusRing(float x, float y) {
    ImageView focusRing = findViewById(R.id.focusRing);

    // Move the focus ring so that its center is at the tap location (x, y)
    float width = focusRing.getWidth();
    float height = focusRing.getHeight();
    focusRing.setX(x - width / 2);
    focusRing.setY(y - height / 2);

    // Show focus ring
    focusRing.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    focusRing.setAlpha(1F);

    // Animate the focus ring to disappear
    focusRing.animate()
        .setStartDelay(500)
        .setDuration(300)
        .alpha(0F)
        .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                focusRing.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            // The rest of AnimatorListener's methods.
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank-You it helped . Have seen your work on the above topic a lot. Appreciate your efforts . If possible please share some documents which would provide me much knowledge on the CameraX library . Thank-You again

Comment: Thank you, this solution solves my problem